# JavaScript - Remove first digit when higher than

Tags: javascript

I have a math formula that sometimes gives an answere above 10000.
What I want is: When the answere is above 10000, for example 21244, I want to echo 1244. Not 21244. In other words, remove the first digit.
Could someone give me an example-script if possible?

Comment: code attempt(s)?

Comment: Can you clarify the rules please? Should a number with more then 4 digits truncate to 4, or is there a special condition?

Comment: What have you tried? Sounds like you need some help with math in general.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: Seems simple enough, what have you tried so far. You mean *"above"* right?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [the remainder (`%`) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) for this:

```js
function limitDigits (x, d) {
  return x % Math.pow(10, d)
}

console.log(limitDigits(21244, 4)) //=> 1244
```

Comment: @gforce301 Remainder is actually not the same as mathematical modulo when it comes to negative numbers. MDN and various other sources refer to the operator as "remainder" in JavaScript even though modulo is a common colloquial term.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the result is saved in variable a.

Logic will be

```
return a % 10000;
```

Comment: You don't need the if statement to use the Modulus operator. 221244 % 10000 = 1244. 3456781244 % 10000 = 1244.

Comment: Modified my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function fun() {
var a = document.getElementById("givenValue").value;
if(a>10000) {
a = a.substr(1);
}
alert('reult : ' + a);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="givenValue" id="givenValue"></input><br/>
<input type="button" value="result" onclick="fun()"/><br/>
```

Check this out